# Override part of a variable

Tags: terraform, hcl

I have a base module which contains the following:

```
locals {
  common_tags = {
    Name          = var.name
    AssetID       = var.AssetID
    AssetName     = var.AssetName
    AssetGroup    = var.AssetGroup
    AssetPurpose  = var.AssetPurpose
    AssetProgram  = var.AssetProgram
    AssetSchedule = var.AssetSchedule
  }
}

output "Tags" {
  value = local.common_tags
}
```

In my other modules I use these tags by importing the module and referencing to it - ie.

```
module "base" {
  source = "../base"
}

resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs_cluster" {
  name  = "my_cluster"
  tags = module.base.Tags
}
```

Now for one of the resources, I need to do the same and use most of the tags apart from one, which will be different ie.

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count             = length(var.aws_zones)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = element(var.aws_zones, count.index)
  cidr_block        = element(var.private_subnets, count.index)
  tags = {
    Name          = "private-${var.name}-${element(var.aws_zones, count.index)}"  
    AssetID       = var.AssetID
    AssetName     = var.AssetName
    AssetGroup    = var.AssetGroup
    AssetPurpose  = var.AssetPurpose
    AssetProgram  = var.AssetProgram
    AssetSchedule = var.AssetSchedule
  }
}
```

Is there a way I can do this without having to rebuild the whole object and having to refer to all these variables in the base module?

Comment: Where are you using that final tags block? You have a count reference so it looks like it's for creating instances across multiple zones? Can you edit the question to include a [mcve] that has that too? If you don't need the count bit and it's just a local block that you want to limit the scope of the question/answer then removing the count reference in the question would simplify the answer too.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR thank you for your comment. I have edited the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ideal case for the [merge function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/merge.html):

```
resource "aws_subnet" "private_subnet" {
  count             = length(var.aws_zones)
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  availability_zone = element(var.aws_zones, count.index)
  cidr_block        = element(var.private_subnets, count.index)
  tags = merge(module.base.tags, {
    Name          = "private-${var.name}-${element(var.aws_zones, count.index)}"  
  })
}
```

> `merge` takes an arbitrary number of maps and returns a single map that contains a merged set of elements from all of the maps.

Comment: this worked but I had to swap the merge inputs ie `merge(module.base.tags, {
    Name          = "private-${var.name}-${element(var.aws_zones, count.index)}"  
  })`

Comment: Good point! You want the additions as overrides! I'll correct that in my answer.